# Read 2 files and output merged lines to 1 file

Tags: python

```
data = data2 = "";

# Reading data from file1
with open('sample1.txt') as fp:
    data = fp.read()

# Reading data from file2
with open('sample2.txt') as fp:
    data2 = fp.read()

# Merging 2 files
# To add the data of file2
# from next line


with open ('sample3.bat', 'a') as fp:
    fp.writelines("KeyHunt-Cuda -m address --coin btc --range " + data + ":" + data2 + "13zb1hQbWVsc2S7ZTZnP2G4undNNpdh5so" '\n')
```

Output on above code

```
KeyHunt-Cuda -m address --coin btc --range aaaa
bbbb
cccc:ddd
eee
fff13zb1hQbWVsc2S7ZTZnP2G4undNNpdh5so
```

File 1

```
aaaa
bbbb
cccc
```

File 2

```
ddd
eee
fff
```

I hoped the output would be like

```
KeyHunt-Cuda -m address --coin btc --range aaaa:ddd 13zb1hQbWVsc2S7ZTZnP2G4undNNpdh5so
KeyHunt-Cuda -m address --coin btc --range bbbb:eee 13zb1hQbWVsc2S7ZTZnP2G4undNNpdh5so
KeyHunt-Cuda -m address --coin btc --range cccc:fff 13zb1hQbWVsc2S7ZTZnP2G4undNNpdh5so
```

How should I change the code?

Comment: What part of your code do you think makes it split up the input and repeat like that?

Comment: To do something *n* times, the most straightforward way is to write a loop. Can you write a loop that prints `aaa` and then `bbb` and then `ccc`? Now can you write a loop that prints `aaa:ddd` and then `bbb:eee` and then `ccc:fff`?

Comment: The problem is pretty clear except it doesn't explain the output being multiple lines. One line, that makes sense - you just need to fiddle with wirtelines a bit.

Comment: @tdelaney Because `data` and `data2` contain the original line breaks.

Comment: @Barmar I am really not sure. I am not a pro and just learning. This is the best I get so far because I need to call each line data from 2 files.

Comment: Computers aren't magic, they just do what you tell them to. If you tell it to concatenate `data`, that's what it does -- it won't figure out that you really wanted it to repeat that for each line.

Comment: `writelines` iterates the data and writes it to the file. Since you only created a single string, it iterated and wrote character by character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `readlines()` to read each file into a list of lines. Then loop over the lines to produce the output you want.

```
# Reading data from file1
with open('sample1.txt') as fp:
    data = fp.readlines()

# Reading data from file2
with open('sample2.txt') as fp:
    data2 = fp.readlines()

with open ('sample3.bat', 'a') as fp:
    for line1, line2 in zip(data, data2):
        fp.write(f"KeyHunt-Cuda -m address --coin btc --range {line1.strip()}:{line2.strip()} 13zb1hQbWVsc2S7ZTZnP2G4undNNpdh5so\n")
```

Comment: OMG.... You solve my problem in a minute and I figuring that for hours. Thank you so much. It works perfectly.

Comment: Computers aren't magic, but I am :)

Comment: You're truly legend, literally in seconds. Thank you very much because it really help so much.

Comment: You can use `zip` on file objects. The first two loops could be redundant.

Comment: @dawg I thought about adding that simplification, I decided not to throw too many things in at once.